# How to manually set GCC as the compiler in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gcc, qt-creator, odroid

I installed QtCreator on an Odroid but it seems to be missing a compiler. I tried the following terminal commands but it did not solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev  libglu1-mesa-dev
```

How can set GCC as the compiler in QtCreator ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a compiler in Tools>Options>Build & Run>Compilers, then switch to the kits tab and add that compiler to the kit you want to use.

The process is described in detail in the manual:
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html for the compiler setup and https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html is about the kits.